# Putting div on div without using absolute

Tags: css, html

Here the website of mine that I'm working on: http://mamgrow.lt/pagrindinis.html

At the very bottom you can see red div block. I need it to move to the top on content. Is it possible without using position:absolute (because I lose center alignment) and top:x?

The thing is, that after I scroll at some point this red div will become fixed (will use jQuery).

For the information div I used this css:

```
.konteineris {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
  position:relative;
}
```

For the red div I used this css:

```
.konteineris2{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:red;
  height:700px;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: You could still center align it...

Comment: without `position` i dont think u'll be able to achieve this in css...not even jquery might help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you use absolute positioning to center align a div on top of another div (or inside another div, you should post your html or make a fiddle).This should not effect your jquery

**Assumed HTML**

```
<div class="konteineris">
  <div class="konteineris2"></div>
</div>
```

**Vertically and Horizontally center aligned**

```
   .konteineris2{
      position:absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin: -350px 0 0 -430px;
    }
```

**Horizontally center aligned**

```
   .konteineris2{
      position:absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 0%;
      margin: 0 0 0 -430px;
    }
```